# Would this be secure?

Tags: authentication, security

I was wondering how secure this would be. I don't have full code for it right now, but I'll try to explain it in words.

When a login button is clicked, using socket.io, the username and password will be sent to a Node Js server. Once the server receives the username and password, it will check a text file, to see if there is a username and password that matches. If there is, the user data will be sent back.

Is there any way that someone could access the text file without direct access to the server? Would this be secure in general?

Answer (score 1):

this will surely get closed as not a coding question, but I will answer anyway.

So you intend to include the user name and password with every request? THats a lot of repeated authentication, use a JWT instead. Use a well known library for auth (like auth0). If you want to make your own mAke sure you send it over https.

Can somebody read the text file?

Well

- do NOT store the password, store a salted hash. This is not reversible so even if the text file gets stolen it doesnt have the password
- in theory nobody can get at the file. In practice there is a huge gap between theory and practice. All the password breaches you hear about are 'bad guys' accessing a file /db that nobody thought could be got at